# Basic Java Mail Session using IMAP throwing Unsupported record version when connecting to Exchange

Tags: java, email, ssl, jakarta-mail

I have a simple setup of Java mail using IMAPS connecting to a Microsoft Exchange 2003 server and trying to retrieve new messages.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", mailUser.getUrl());
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", MAIL_TIMEOUT_MS);
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
    javax.mail.Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props);
    mailSession.setDebug(false);
    Store store = mailSession.getStore();
    Folder inbox = null;
    try
    {
        byte[] encryptedPassword = mailUser.getEncryptedPassword();
        String encryptedPasswordStr = encryptedPassword == null ? "" : new String(encryptedPassword);
        store.connect(mailUser.getUrl(), mailUser.getUsername(), encryptedPasswordStr);
        inbox = store.getFolder(INBOX_FOLDER_NAME);
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        int unreadMessageCount = inbox.getUnreadMessageCount();
        if (unreadMessageCount > 0)
        {
            Message[] mailMessages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
            for (javax.mail.Message mailMessage : mailMessages)
            {
                try
                {
                    processMessage(mailMessage);
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    LOGGER.error("Unable to parse message header for message.  Skipping", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        store.close();
    }
```

The SSL Imap Store gets created correctly but when connect is called the SSL connections gets set up correctly with all of the certificate parts looking good in java logs then after the connection is setup I get this error:

```
INFO  [AbstractLoggingWriter] EJB default - 1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-11.48
INFO  [AbstractLoggingWriter] %% Invalidated:  [Session-25, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
INFO  [AbstractLoggingWriter] EJB default - 1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:fatal, description = unexpected_message
```

The client hello, the server hello, and the server hello done all come through and look good.  The IMAP logs on the exchange server just report successful connections.  Any ideas?

Comment: First, you're using the "imaps" protocol, which means all your "mail.imap.*" properties are being ignored.  Just use the "imap" protocol and set "mail.imap.ssl.enable" to "true".

Comment: I've never seen that SSL error but it seems to be coming from the JDK's SSL support, not JavaMail.  What JDK version are you using?  Is there any firewall between client and server?  Can you connect to the same server from the same client machine using the [JavaMail msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples)?  How about from other machines?  Try enabling SSL debugging as described in [SSLNOTES.txt](http://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Bill.  I tried the sample program and got the same result.  I tried from multiple systems with no firewall between and the same error is present.  I turned on SSL debugging and it finds the correct cert and the debug ends with `certpath: Cert path validation succeeded. (PKIX validation algorithm)`  I'm running JDK 1.7.0_97.  Any other things I should check?

Comment: I don't think this problem is at all associated with JavaMail.  I think it's a JDK SSL related problem, so you probably need a JDK SSL expert to interpret the debug output.  It sounds like it might somehow be related to the cipher suites that are being used.  You're using a pretty old version of Exchange; perhaps it has a bug?   Or perhaps it is using old cipher suites that the JDK no longer supports or no longer enables by default?  I would expect something in the debug output if that was the case.  If you connect to Gmail instead of Exchange, does it work?

Comment: @Bill I do agree that it doesn't seem to be a JavaMail problem.  It has to be something with the JDK SSL or the exchange server.

Comment: I ended up having to specify a cipher suite that exchange 2003 could handle, I had to use SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA